# Witch Doctor build for Inferno?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I am in the beginning of Inferno and I am having a bit of trouble some places, I have been using the zombie bears build ([this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#fZUdQP!UcZ!caZZZY) or a variant of it), while the damage is very nice and it is a very good build for groups I find some champion packs/elites are impossible to take out with it when running solo. So what is a more well rounded build for soloing Inferno as a Witch Doctor?

Answer (score 3):

So far I've used two builds with a decent amount of success soloing Inferno Acts 1 and 2 (just grinding for gear and killing champion packs and the end boss). Honestly, the best and most powerful thing you can do in Inferno is just gear yourself up. I've heard of a lot of random builds working, as long as you gear yourself in a specific way and have a pretty decent weapon. Also, using the Templar pet while soloing is a good idea, since he will actually tank for you.

As far as a specific build for soloing champions in inferno, I've had pretty good luck with a [poison dart build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#aZSeUT!ZWV!aacYcc). For this to be successful you'll need to stack a little bit of attack speed and have a pretty decent weapon though. You'll also need to prioritize abilities that'll let you kite. I like the DoTs because they also help with large packs and you don't just get melted, but you can probably change out some of that stuff for your own personal preferences for your own play style.

I like the ZomBears build, but I do agree that it is difficult to solo with because you've got to be fairly close for it to work. I've been playing around with build alternatives and so far I've only come up with the Poison Dart build.

Editing this in since I just tried a new variant of poison dart build that I liked more. [This build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#aeXRUT!ZWV!aYZacc) for darts was much more effective due to the amount of CC you gain from Horrify and Hex. I had a much easier time doing solo Inferno Butcher runs with this build that my previously mentioned one.

[Link to ZomBear build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#fZdRUT!XUb!caaacc) I used for a while that also worked well.

[This Pet Build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#ecUYTd!Ueg!ZbZaZZ) has also been said to be pretty effective, but I've not tested it much myself. It looks interesting though, and a couple of people on Blizzard's Witch Doctor forums have said it is good.

Comment: the 2nd build you posted for your darts was extremely ineffective for me...i just died to four spiders (teleport, extra health, mortar) in hell act 2. the CC is a good idea, but it's extremely situational. the giant just dies a lot and stuns maybe 2 times in his lifetime. I have a little under 11k damage and 2.21 attacks/second. The CC is good, but I ended up just running around with almost no health (around 2k out of 25k).

Comment: Hmm. I've not come across any issues like that with it. The situation is different though so would be hard for me to be able to test. Pretty much any WD build is going to have a rough time with Tele/Mort creatures though because they're difficult to kite.

Comment: seems like any poison dart build would require roughly 2.00+as with high amount of dps, else you'll be kiting forever.

Answer (score 2):

I use **spirit walk (mana regen)** to go into the pack  then active **soul harvest (life steal 9K HP + 650 Int)** then go back from a few metters **slow with the 80% Area** and throwing **bears** with my **Zombies Wall just in front of me** so i have these 4 spells in CD ==> **300% regen mana (masterie)** ==> **unlimited bears** ... until the slows stop (8 sec duraction /// 8 sec CD ) then recast the slow few meters back, back a little w8ting spirit walk and harvest (both 15 sec CD) and start over.

with masterie +10% mana/ globe and some range of grabbing the 2nd spirit walk grab 3-4 globes granting **+30-40% int + 650 + 9k HP from harvest + globes ==> double my int ==> double dmgs  and full life**

if i can t kill the guy before they reach me and they kill me i got masteries that saves me and i back, slow and start again the combo :-D

i advise some grabbing range and some bonus life on globes so u can never die :-D

PS : sry for the terms, i don t realy know the names of the skills in english ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is my build](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#WZUdiT!ZYe!baZZaZ).

As with most WD builds, the main focus here is on mobility. While spamming Grasp and having several Fetishes out at any time, the mobs are generally caught up either being slowed or swinging at Fetishes/Gargantuan.

You can stack high damage by Soul Harvest and the passive Gruesome Feast, enabling some high initial/DoT Acid Clouds (note that it has the Acid Rain rune, hitting more mobs with the initial). Gargantuan and Fetishes also [benefit from Int boosts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67784/do-stat-boosts-affect-dot-effects-already-in-play).

The primary, **Rain of Toads**, is basically a concentrated Acid Cloud with higher damage in smaller radius, and is highly stackable. Use it for champions, elites, and other key mobs like spawners.

If you're low on mana after dropping several Acid Clouds, Spirit Walk will gain you *some* mana. I mainly Spirit Walk to hunt the area for dropped Globes which will provide additional mana *and* boost your Int.

Answer (score 1):

My build
http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#aZUTjX!ZWV!aaaZbY

Not sure if anyone else still reads this but here's my build.  I've found it pretty useful with DPS from 14k-30k.  ATK% and Regeneration are great for this build.

Basically Grasp where you want to control the field, and let the Garg take the front while you pepper with Darts.  When things get close use your crowd controls starting with Confuse, anything not caught with the Confuse is stunned and Spirit yourself away and place a new Grasp.  Save your Horrify for the armor buff and Confuse cooldown.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone take advantage of stun/immobilize/freeze gear paired with mana regen.  Most of my gear has a chance to do one of the above.  I use Garg and zombie dogs with acid rain and posion darts and spirit walk with mana regen when my mana runs out and big bad voodoo rain dance for large packs and/or elites.  It works great on hell diablo and so far is ok in inferno.

Answer (score 1):

I've completed inferno with the witchdoctor. There seems to be a lot of BS running around here so I'll clear the air, take it or leave it.

My build: Poison darts (splinters), Bats (Dire bats), Spirit Walk (the one that extends the duration of the walk), soul harvest (increase damage), Big Bad Voodoo (use mana regen one normally, and damage increase one for doing Belial farms *You need to kill him quickly*), Confuse (increase radius)

Spirit walk into packs to cast soul harvest buff, and spirit walk whenever it's off cooldown will save you a lot. Passives use spirit vessel, vision quest, and the one that decreases damage 20%. I cannot stress the importance of having spirit vessel as it has saved me time and again from a hefty repair bill. I also can't stress enough the importance of dire bats. They chew up a lot of mana, but they have excellent range and go through targets and do area damage twice if not three times as powerful as poison darts. With a decent weapon like a ceremonial blade that does somewhere around 1000 dps and a lot of INT stacked you can mow enemies over all the way through inferno with dire bats.

Also you're not trying very hard with gear farming if you get one shotted by anything in inferno. Stack 600-700 resist all (not hard to do) and with 30k health you can take quite a few shots.

Pets are the worst idea for inferno, lose the pets. bears are to limiting with their piss poor range. An act 3 champ pack will destroy you in a few quick shots if you are relying on bears as a skill. You need to kite with bats.

Comment: Many people do quite well in Act 3 against champ packs with bears. You do not *need* to kite with bats.  Both are perfectly viable, so claiming one is and the other is not is wrong.

Comment: Because people were using vision quest to spam with bears, which is conterproductive enough for blizzard to notice so they will be changing that skill all together. Having 4 skills on CD is just plain stupid, it handicaps you from playing the game an intelligent way. I contend that those so-called "people doing well with bears" could never solo their way through inferno, but rather are co-oping where that build can actually be viable. I've seen and tested this first hand and you cannot solo inferno with a bears build and not spend mucho dinero on repair costs.

Comment: Perhaps you cannot solo inferno with a bears build, but others absolutely have. Your claims that it is impossible are factually incorrect.  The parts about VQ being "stupid" are subjective, and don't really belong here (not saying I disagree; just that answers here are expected to represent fact and/or direct assistance to the main question, rather than tangential discussion of opinion).

Answer (score 0):

The zombie bear build works great once you time when to hit spirit walk to do the most damage then to run and kite the mobs until you use the bears again.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit Inferno, and was surprised at just how well my zombear build's been working: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#TfUdR!ZUV!ccZZa.  I left the 4th skill blank since I haven't decided what I like best (I'm probably going to go with horrify/frightening aspect for the armor bonus).  The key is that when you have 4 cooldowns with vision quest you can zombear pretty much indefinitely.

I threw the bruiser to left-mouse since it made it easier to move without attacking something instead, but basically when I see enemies or a boss pack, I make sure bruiser/hex are on cooldown, and rush in spirit walk/soulharvest then zombears for a few seconds to do as much dmg as possible.  Then I dodge/kite while casting zombears when I can to take out what didn't die initially.  The bruiser's stun and hex keep enough enemies down that it's usually pretty quick to mop up all but the really nasty boss packs.

I just have cheap gear I picked up at the AH (10k damage base = 30-40k zombears, 40k life or so)

Answer (score -1):

Vision Quest build is by far the best build. I've solod and strolled through hell barely ever taking a death. im in act 2 inferno now, and it obviously wont matter what build you use, youre getting 1 hit ko'ed

Comment: You are not adding anything that hasn't already been said.  If you're getting 1 hit, why aren't you changing your build to account for that?

Answer (score -1):

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#aUZSdT!ZWV!acacZc
My build - It works ok because of my massive attack speed.

Comment: Please elaborate on exactly why this build works.  Just posting a link is not a good answer.