# Honestly, is there anything better than Zombie Bears?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Witch Doctor build for Inferno?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70253/witch-doctor-build-for-inferno)

I've been playing a Witch Doctor for a while now, and have just reached Act II of Inferno.  Needless to say, ever since I unlocked it I've been using a zombears build for pretty much everything.  I have to wonder, are there any other truly viable builds for a WD in Inferno?  I've toyed around with some other ideas from time to time, but the overarching problem is that the DPS just isn't there compared to zombears.  No other skill seems to come close in terms of damage output, which means that even skills that let you stay further away from enemies don't work- it takes three times the time to kill said enemies, so you end up exposed to damage anyway.

I mean, my build does work, but it makes me wonder: does anything else?  I'd love to hear of a WD in Inferno who's managed with something else.

[My build is here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/witch-doctor#fPYUdT!Uea!ccYaZZ).  Comments or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

==========

EDIT: Just to clear things up; I'm aware that there are tons of build ideas floating around the internet. What I'd really like isn't just an idea for a good build, but an idea for a build that can be *strongly argued* to be better than a zombears build.  I can't imagine a build that beats zombears for DPS, so if someone could provide some other compelling reason, such as increased survivability, adaptability, etc., *that's* what I'm looking for. Having played other builds in the past I've always come back to zombears, so at this point I'm really not convinced that anything else is as good.  I know there must be people who think differently, so I'd like to hear from them.

Comment: keep in mind that in the next couple of weeks, patch 1.04 is buffing many underused skills to create more viable builds

Comment: I didn't know that!  It will be interesting to see if anything is a game changer.  I for one would love for it to be more viable to create a working pets build.  After all, isn't that what the WD should be about?

Comment: Your edit turns this question into soliciting opinions and discussion, and as such, is not a good fit for our Q&A format, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zombie Bears is the best burst damage, no question.

But that doesn't make it the "best build".

[Direbats](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/firebats) can be substituted for Zombie Bears in many builds to change from short-range burst damage to long-range kiting.

Other builds rely on procs such as Life on Hit or Chance to x (stun/blind/immobilize/fear/etc.) to reduce incoming damage, and in those builds there are many other skills that provide more benefit than Zombie Bears, such as Acid Cloud, Big Stinker, Rain of Corpses,or Zombie Dog.  The reason these are superior in the proc builds is that they hit far more often per cast than Zombie Bears, and the [Life on Hit coefficient for Zombie Bears is very low](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271499223) (meaning that you get roughly 25% of the stated LoH value for each hit of a Zombie Bear).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! My understanding is that CC effects have a reduced chance to proc in Inferno; are they still viable given that liability?  I used a CC build a while back (Nightmare) and it worked fairly well, though finding gear was a big issue.  I ended up being too gimped to be able to carry on with it.  I'd attempt a Fierce Loyalty build but for the same reason; it's hard to find equipment to make such a build worthwhile.

Comment: I have not heard that CC has a reduced chance to proc.  Lifeleech, yes (it is much less effective). Other procs, not that I'm aware of. I haven't personally tried it, but I know a number of WDs who ran about 7-10% CC effect (combined) and reported that most encounters became laughable because the enemies were unable to attack during most of the fight (the sheer number of chances some of the skills listed give for these procs means they are going off constantly).

Comment: Interesting.  Yeah, I found that even with my ad hoc CC build on Nightmare, I could even stun-lock Diablo himself into oblivion.  I haven't tried CC since because of lack of gear, as well as because I thought the effects were reduced as I mentioned.  Perhaps if I can find some appropriate gear I'll give it another try.