# Are damage over time effects buffed retroactively from damage buffs?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I cast Haunt on an enemy and it's ticking along, and then later cast Piranhas on the same enemy (which gives a 15% damage bonus against affected enemies), will Haunt do more damage for the duration of the Piranhas, or does Haunt have to be re-cast to gain the effects of the new damage buff?

Comment: How "stat boosts" are the same as "damage buffs"??? I am thoroughly puzzled with how this could have been closed, and am upset.

Comment: @OrcJMR The asker was the first to vote it as dupe.  I suspect he knows what he's doing.

Comment: @Frank, okay, but in Diablo 3 there's no direct relation between main stat, that boosts base weapon damage, and abilities, that increase received damage from all sources by a percent. Not until it is proven, there isn't. I may be blissfully ignorant about the game, and that's why I fail to grasp the logic.

Comment: @OrcJMR Eh?  ALL abilities that do damage come from weapon damage.  Every single one.  That's how damage is derived.

Comment: @Frank But *weapon's damage* being modified by main stat and *total skill damage* being further modified by another skill are veery far apart in the calculation order, wouldn't you agree? And nothing indicates these two operations are performed identically, that's what I mean.

Comment: Oops. Somehow I misread *my own question* when I voted to close.

Comment: Loosely related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67784/do-stat-boosts-affect-dot-effects-already-in-play

Answer (score 1):

thats a good one, the damage is calculated on the moment it is cast/inflickted.

example:

haunt causes 2 damage per sec.
i cast piranhas to get a piranha on Diablo's nose, +15% DMG!
Haunt causes still 2 damage per sec untill cast again

Answer (score 0):

They *shoudn't*.

Now, I can not say for sure about **Haunt** and **Piranhas**, and even if I could, anything could change tomorrow with a hotfix.

What I am getting at, though, is that Blizzard has successively fixed those pairs of skills/effects that "*snapshot*" damage. The reason for fixes is the opposite of what you describe - some builds are able to field a significant damage/skill bonus for a short while, and damage over time effects applied during that timeframe would "snapshot" the increased damage and continue to deal it for a significant amount if time, even after buffs have fallen off.

I cannot find mentions of skills being fixed in such fashion in hotfix logs since 2.0.1, and the only mention in patch notes is that before 2.1.0 Ancients did snapshot attack speed when summoned. But [latest](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/15698856044) [hotfixes](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11760375956) mention fixes to legendary item procs snapshotting quite a bit.