# Does Hexing Pants of Mr. Yan work for Sentry/Hydra skill?

Tags: diablo-iii

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hexing-pants-of-mr-yan

> Your resource generation and damage is increased by 25% while moving
>   and decreased by 20–25% while standing still.

I'm wondering whether it works for Demon Hunter's Sentry skill, or similarly Wizard's Hydra skill. I mean, can I just put Sentries/Hydras on the ground and then start running around them to make them deal 20-25% more damage, whether I'm moving or not when I cast the skill? Or I just need to be moving when I cast the skill to enjoy the damage boost for the whole duration of Sentries/Hydras , whether I keep running or not after casting? Or I need to both be moving when casting and keep running after casting?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67784/do-stat-boosts-affect-dot-effects-already-in-play

Answer (score 3):

The damage increase should show up in your sheet damage as long as you are moving. Since hydra and sentry damage is based on your own damage, it should apply to them as well.
I know of people who use Hexing Pants of Mr.Yan on their Witch Doctors with pet builds and it works great.

Tested just now (don't have the pants, I took my weapon off, cast hydra, put the weapon back on) - the damage of hydra is calculated at the moment of cast and doesn't change when your damage changes unless you recast, so you will have to be moving when you cast hydra, but you don't have to keep moving once it's summoned.

Comment: the question is whether or not those skills snapshot your dps at the time of cast though.  If they do, then you have to make sure you are moving when you cast, the buff wears off quite fast when you stop moving.

Comment: @z good point. I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: updated answer to reflect the changes in question

Comment: I'm a bit confused. How can you test if you don't have Hexing Pants?

Comment: Hexing pants increase/decrease your sheet damage, by changing my sheet damage, I can test if it affects the mentioned skills. If you have Hexing pants and can prove me wrong, you are more than welcome to do so :)